# Proof that the Markov Blanket in a Bayesian Network is parents, children, and children's parents

Tags: bayesian, graphical-model, bayesian-network

I'm looking for a proof of this fact from wikipedia:

> The Markov boundary of a node $A$ in a Bayesian network is the set of nodes composed of $A$'s parents, $A$'s children, and $A$'s children's other parents.

I haven't yet seen a really convincing argument for why it's exactly this set and nothing more. Like, why are $A$'s children's parent's parents not important?

Can someone provide a proof of this fact? I think what we want to show is:

Let $B$ be the set of nodes composed of $A$'s parents, $A$'s children, and parents of $A$'s children (the Markov Boundary). For any node $X$ not in $B$, we want to show that
$P(X,A|B)=P(X|B)P(A|B)$. We want to say something about every path from $X$ to $A$ being 'blocked off' by the Markov blanket, but I'm not sure how to formalize this.

Comment: See [Markov condition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_Markov_condition).

Comment: @mhdadk The link you provided doesn't provide a proof though? It just asserts that the local Markov property results in this Markov blanket. There is no proof.